# Unable to send a post request using POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I am trying to make a post call to `https://api2.realtor.ca/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post`.

I am able to do this using a node library *realtorca*, but I would like to make this call using Postman. I am obviously new to Postman and these REST calls so I am having a tough time.

When I looked at `realtorca.js`, it is basically doing

```js
return request({
            method: 'POST',
            uri: API_URL,
            form: form,
            json: true
        });
```

where API_URL is `'https://api2.realtor.ca/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post'`
and form is

```js
{ CultureId: 1,
  ApplicationId: 1,
  PropertySearchTypeId: 1,
  LongitudeMin: -81.277602,
  LongitudeMax: -81.271602,
  LatitudeMin: 43.038275,
  LatitudeMax: 43.044275 }
```

I know this has to be simple but I tried lots of different variations and can't figure this out.

Comment: Can you share the error message

Comment: It's working fine from my Postman. In the server app, `FormData` and `raw json` will result in `The request was invalid. (hidden)`. So yeah,  make sure you use `POST` method and `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me posting with x-www-form-urlencoded

[image]

Comment: that works, i gave u a thumbs up but i guess my reputation isn't high enough to show up

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I'm using Postman, I have to use quotation marks on my object's variable names.

Maybe try 
`{ 
  "CultureId": 1,
  "ApplicationId": 1,
  "PropertySearchTypeId": 1,
  "LongitudeMin": -81.277602,
  "LongitudeMax": -81.271602,
  "LatitudeMin": 43.038275,
  "LatitudeMax": 43.044275 
}`

Comment: I tried that, would it possible for you provide some screen shots?

Comment: Is the data type set to JSON? The button next to "Pretty," "Raw," and "Preview."